# Android + NodeJS facing Socket.io XHR connection issues

Tags: android, node.js, http, websocket, socket.io

I am using NodeJS server and an Android client, but at the moment of creating the Socket.IO connection, I keep receiving XHR error.
Find here the troubleshooting I have done.

Client side:

The permissions are already configured.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

In a separate class I have the following:

```
        try {
            socketio = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.76:3001/");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

In the server side I have the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

server.listen(3001,"0.0.0.0", () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3001');
});
```

The IP that I am using in the socket is from here:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : lan
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2001:818:e2d4:6600:383e:7231:7f32:4c0
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:818:e2d4:6600:d556:2d6c:bbd4:ecf1
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d556:2d6c:bbd4:ecf1%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.76
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

And the error I keep receiving is this one:

```
V/Socket Test: com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error
```

I would appreciate any help.